# According to the Vedas The Antim sanskar should it be 13 days or 3 days or one day?

Tags: vedas, rituals

According to the Vedas or Gita does the Antim sanskar last 3 days, 13 days or one day? Is there any written instructions in any veda or the Gita?

Comment: Although this link does not Answer exact days, but its interesting reading about 16-Sanskar commonly practised as per Hinduism: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/410/what-are-the-16-sanskaar-sacraments-of-life-and-how-do-you-complete-them

Comment: The instructions are in Garuda Purana...

Comment: Are you talking about period of impurity or mourning after death in family(also known as ashoucha), or the period of main cremation rite and tarpan process?

Comment: Cremation/burial must happen asap. Other "poojas" depend on the varna/caste.

Comment: Vedas do not mention it. Puranas or smritis have such rules. Vedas tag is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Veda and Gita talk about SPIRITUALITY in most of the places, Puranas talk about rituals.

In Ramayana it was mentioned that Bharata got himself purified on 12th Day and collected the bones on the 13th day.

> ततः दश अहे अतिगते कृत शौचो नृप आत्मजः | द्वादशे अहनि सम्प्राप्ते
>   श्राद्ध कर्माणि अकारयत् || २-७७-१
>
> After having passed the tenth day of the death of Dasaratha, Bharata
>   **having himself purified**, performed Shraddha* rites on the arrival of
>   the **twelfth day**.
>
> ततः प्रभात समये दिवसे अथ त्रयोदशे || २-७७-४ विललाप महा बाहुर् भरतः शोक
>   मूर्चितः | शब्द अपिहित कण्ठः च शोधन अर्थम् उपागतः || २-७७-५ चिता मूले
>   पितुर् वाक्यम् इदम् आह सुदुह्खितः |
>
> Then, at the time of dawn on the **thirteenth day**, the mighty armed
>   Bharata who came for clearing up bones and ashes, wept in grief, his
>   throat being choked of sound (because of crying) and spoke in great
>   distress the following words, having reached the foot of his father's
>   funeral pile (to collect the bones and ashes for their immersion in
>   Sarayu River).

Comment: Vedas talk about all sorts of Karma. In fact, only mainly Upanishads talk about moksha. Vedangas like Kalpa Sutra and Jyotisha talk about these rituals, not only puranas.