# What is the meaning of word Sanskara?

Tags: rituals

Recently I participated in the Antim Sanskara of my Father in Law.
Also we say that " He or She is very Sanskari. "
In both the context word Sanskar is used.

My questions are : What is the meaning of the word Sanskara?

Do animals also have Sanskaras?

Comment: It means a sacrament. See questions tagged under [tag:samskara] and also [What are the 16 sanskaar (Sacraments of Life) and How do you complete them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/410/5212)

Comment: The answer given by you fails when we say " He or She is very Sanskari."

Comment: It does because you are comparing oranges and apples. Both are different. One word has many meanings. She is a sanskari means "She is reformed". Sanskara means reform or a sacrament done for the reform one's life. Antim samskara done is one of the sixteen sacraments and the last one. So, this is the correct meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many meanings for Sanskara or Saṃskāra (संस्कार):

> putting together
>
> making perfect
>
> consecrations
>
> behavioral traits
>
> dispositions
>
> accomplishing well

---

A Grihastha (householder) has 3 kinds of duties/rituals/consecrations:

> - ***Nitya*** (regular),
> - ***Naimaitik*** (causal) and
> - ***NityaNaimaitik*** (a combination of both). - [Markandeya Purana](https://archive.org/stream/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi#page/n131/mode/1up)

Most of the Samskaras from the list of 16 Samskaras (Ṣoḍaśa Saṃskāra) generally falls under Naimaitik (causal) rituals/consecrations category.

The sanskaras vary in number and details. They range from the list of 40 sanskaras in the *Gautama Dharmasutra* to 16 sanskaras in the *Grhyasutra*.

The behavioral traits such as compassion, patience, non-envy, purity of thought speech & body, inner calm & peace, positive attitude and generosity etc. also comes under Saṃskāras.

---

***Antyesthi or Antim Sanskar (Cremation)*** is part of 16 Samskaras as disscussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/410/what-are-the-16-sanskaar-sacraments-of-life-and-how-do-you-complete-them).

---

When someone says "***He or She is very Sanskari***"; they refer behavioral traits of a person such as compassion, patience, non-envy, purity of thought speech & body, inner calm & peace, positive attitude and generosity etc. which are included in 40 sanskaras. [सदाचार (morality or good behavior
)](https://archive.org/stream/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi#page/n141/mode/1up) is also closely related with the statement "*He or She is very Sanskari*".

Answer (score 4):

P.V Kane  - in his book [**History Of Dharmasastra Vol II Part I**](https://archive.org/stream/historyofdharmas029210mbp#page/n247/mode/2up) is quoting  the meaning of **word samskara given by Sabara Swami in his commentary of Jaiminis Purva Mimansa sutras 1.1.3 and Kumarila Bhatta in Tantra-Vartika .**

> संस्कारो नाम स भवति यस्मिञ्जाते पदार्थो भवति योग्य : कस्य चिदर्थ स्य |
>
> Sabara explains samskara as that which being affected makes certail
>   thing or a person fit for certain purpose..

---

And Kumarila Bhatta in Tantra-Vartika (a commentary on Śabara's Bhāṣya on the Pūrvamīmāṃsā sūtras of Jaimini)  says that

> योग्यतां चादधाना: क्रिया : संस्कारा इत्युच्चते |
>
> "Samskaras" are those actions and rites that impart fitness. Fitness
>   is of two kinds ;it arises by removal of taints (sins) or by the
>   generations of freash qualities.

## see Point 448 & footnote on the page.

Comment: Can I say that knowing what is good and what is bad is a result of Sanskar?

Comment: Not completely , We have to read vedas /shastras ,also  Gurus guidance and teachings are required in order to know good and what is bad. That means a lot of other things are also required and not only Sanskar. But certainly Sanskar (by anyone Parents /Guru) plays a vital role. I will update you on this point later on.