# Were there sacraments to convert non-arya and arya but non-kshatriya kings to kshatriyas?

Tags: history, caste-system, varna, kshatriya

Wiki article of Mahapadma Nanda [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahapadma_Nanda#Life)

> The Puranas describe Mahapadma as a son of Mahanandin by a woman from the Shudra caste.[ Jain works like Parishishtaparvan and Avashyaka sutra represent him as the son of a courtesan by a barber. Curtius, a Roman historian, informs us that
>
> > his father was in fact a barber, scarcely staving off hunger by his daily earnings, but who, from his being not uncomely in person, had gained the affections of the queen, and was by her influence advanced to too near a place in the confidence of reigning monarch. Afterwards, however, he treacherously murdered his sovereign, and then, under the pretence of acting as guardian to the royal children, usurped the supreme authority, and having put the young princes to death begot the present king.
> >         — Curtius"

Did the Brahmins perform sacraments to make such kings Kshatriyas?

Comment: There are no such rites. One who is born in the Kshatriya family is a Kshatriya. And if he fails to receive the sacraments at the right time then he becomes fallen (he is called a Vratya then and he for all purposes is regarded as one the non-Aryans)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Brahmins performed such rituals which turned non Kshatriyas to Kshatriyas.

One such instance is Hiranya Garbha (literally Golden Womb) ritual performed by [Dantidurga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dantidurga), who is the founder of [Rashtrakuta dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashtrakuta_dynasty) who overthrew Chalukya Dynasty of Karnataka. He was not a kshatriya by birth but turned to a Kshatriya after performing this ritual.

Hiranya Garbha Mahaadaana is one of the sixteen Mahaadaanas.

1. Tulapurusha
2. **Hiranyagarbha**
3. Brahmanda,
4. Kalpapadapa,
5. Gosahasra,
6. Kamadhenu (or Hiranya-Kamadhenu),
7. Hiranyasva,
8. Hiranyashvaratha,
9. Hemahastiratha,
10. Panchalañgalaka.
11. Dhara,
12. Vishvachakra,
13. Kalpalata (or Mahdkalpalata),
14. Saptasagara,
15. Ratnadhenu and
16. Mahabhütaghata,

Among these Rulapurusha and Hiranyagarbha maahaadaanas are famous

Dantidurga performed a ritual at Ujjaini named Hiranya Garbha which is believed to give a rebirth to the sacrificer who performed it. It will be considered as a new birth from that moment.

Matsya Purana Chapter 273 and 274 are dedicated to explain these above two rituals in detail.

By performing the ritual, the sacrificer gets a rebirth and the samskaras like Garbhadana, Punsavana and Simanta are done to the Hiranyagarbha. All the [sixteen sacraments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/410/5212) are performed to the devotee by the brahmins. After this, the brahmanas chant some mantras and that is considered a new birth to the devotee performing the mahaadaana.

> O Best of the Devas’ as I was born of you in the mortal world so **let me be born again of Divine form on account of my being born again of you**.. You have created me virtuous and trut1iuI. Afterwards the Brähmana should
>   dccorte a blessed cow with the ornaments and bathe her with four Vases. He should sear her on the golden seat and bathe her by reciting these
>   mantras, viz.•- “Devasya tvá” etc. and say “I shall now bathe all the limbs born of you”  [Chapter 274 verses 20-22]

From [new world encyclopedia site](http://web.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Rashtrakuta_Dynasty),

> The Sanjan inscriptions tell of King Amoghavarsha I sacrificing a finger from his left hand at the Lakshmi temple at Kolhapur to avert a calamity in his kingdom. **King Dantidurga performed the Hiranyagarbha** and the Sanjan and Cambay plates of King Govinda IV mention Brahmins performing such rituals as Rajasuya, Vajapeya and Agnishtoma.

Dantidurga performed Hiranyagarbha ritual and it is recorded in the Sanjan inscriptions.  After that, other kings also accepted him as a Kshatriya and he became a powerful ruler.