# What is the significance of 11th day ritual after death?

Tags: rituals, death

After the death of a person,a ritual/ceremony will be held on the 11th day. What is the significance ?

People from different community will held on different date such as on the 9th,14th or 16th day . Actually,when should the ritual/ceremony be held after death ? Is it on the 11th day or 16th day? (please answer according to scripture)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of 3, 16, or 41 days after the death?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-is-the-significance-of-3-16-or-41-days-after-the-death)

Comment: Well that might be because soul remains at home for 10 days after death and then leaves on the 11th day. Have a look at [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13824/3872).