# Is it true, only married people are cremated, non-married people are buried?

Tags: rituals, death

I need to know what are the situations that one should be cremated or buried in Hinduism.

This is with reference to married or unmarried persons cremation process. If there is different rituals in sects we being Hindu should know it.

Comment: [Jayalalitha?](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/Why-Jayalalithaa-was-given-a-burial/article16769474.ece)

Comment: Yup, but this is in general question. One should know

Comment: No only infants & children are buried not the unmarried adults.

Comment: People after living for a long time get attached to the body, this is the reason why their body is cremated, only in case of children and saints, they are buried, the reason being children have hardly lived long enough to get attached to body and saints have already realized body to be Maya so they don't care for the body either.

Comment: @iammilind In J Jayalalitha's case it is said that she was buried on her own wish because she wanted to be buried alongside MGR(some say it was enforcement of party rules which is totally atheist). Since MGR was originally Keralite bramhin, they have a tradition of burying people (yes even in bramhins) instead of cremation. So if we see that from a Keralite point of view it would be correct(no citations/proofs heard on a news channel).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do hindus believe in cremation instead of burial](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36/why-do-hindus-believe-in-cremation-instead-of-burial "why do hindus believe in cremation instead of burial").

Comment: @SreeCharan This is related to the other one, but a very specific question, so not a dup. of the other.

Comment: @sv. Yes but this question is already answered long ago in the above question. See the answer. If you insist, I will retract my vote.

Comment: @SreeCharan I read the accepted answer just now, yes, it says children and saints are exception to cremation but it's not talking about married or unmarried people specifically. Also it lacks references being an old answer. But the question there is very generic and this is specific. You can keep your vote, let others also vote & decide.